# Looking for science fiction mention LASER

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a specific science-fiction short story with a quote saying that

> "LASER used for the first time in 1962".

I read it in a translated book in Arabic named "*Secret Under Ice*" which didn't name the author.

I think the original story is probably published in late 1960s or 1970s because the book was published in the 1980s.

The beginning of the book facing the editor-in-chief of the newspaper "Stories from the World" called Carlos Diaper and two journalists working with him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you looking for a specific story?  If so, can you give us any more details about it?  When did you read it?  Where?

Comment: I read it in  a translated book in arabic without mention the author named " secret under ice " . I think the original story is probably published in late 1960s or 1970s because the book is published in 1980s

Comment: Thank you - I have added this information in to the question. Please do add anything else you remember.

Comment: Do you remember the exact Arabic title, rather than what it translates to in English? Maybe googling that would turn up more information, like the author.